# Vagrant up error after Windows 10 Anniversary Update

Tags: vagrant, virtualbox

I am trying to vagrant up after windows 10 anniversary update, and I get an error:

```
$ vagrant up
Bringing machine 'default' up with 'virtualbox' provider...
==> default: Checking if box 'scotch/box' is up to date...
==> default: Resuming suspended VM...
==> default: Booting VM...
There was an error while executing `VBoxManage`, a CLI used by Vagrant
for controlling VirtualBox. The command and stderr is shown below.

Command: ["startvm", "5c441fcf-c08f-4adb-8318-532107a81da3", "--type",     "headless"]

Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Nonexistent host networking interface, name 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' (VERR_INTERNAL_ERROR)
VBoxManage.exe: error: Details: code E_FAIL (0x80004005), component ConsoleWrap, interface IConsole
```

Before the update everything worked fine. I tried reinstall the newest version of VirtualBox and Vagrant also, but it doesn't help.

Any help is appreciated.

Comment: Do you launch vagrant as Administrator (sometimes it helps)?

Comment: Vagrant complains about the 'VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #2' - can you check if it exists? If no -  I would suggest reinstalling VirtualBox

Comment: @RuslanBes: thanks this was a good idea.  the #2 adatper was not found.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

Like @RusalBes sad the #2 adatper was not found. Therefore I went the Network Adapter setting in VirtualBox on that machine when the adapter name was not the "#2" instead of the normal "VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter". Than I've just clicked OK and than everything works fine. :) I hope this will help others.

[image: VirtualBox adapter setting]

Comment: same thing worked for the Windows 10 Creators Update.

Comment: For me the only option was #3 - but as soon as I just click the dropdown and then clicked OK my vagrant box would start again. Go figure...

Answer (score 5):

I had the same issue. I tried upgrading VirtualBox and Vagrant. Then I downgraded to VirtualBox 5.0, but it still didn't work. Fortunately, I discovered [this post](https://forums.virtualbox.org/viewtopic.php?f=6&t=68590&start=450#p345381), which basically showed that enabling the "VirtualBoxNDIS6 Bridged Network Driver" option in the "VirtualBox Host-Only Network" adapter properties in Network Settings resolved the issue. After doing that, everything began working again as expected.

Here's the image from that post:

[image]

Comment: For whatever reason, you still get this error: Stderr: VBoxManage.exe: error: Failed to open/create the internal network 'HostInterfaceNetworking-VirtualBox Host-Only Ethernet Adapter #3' (VERR_INTNET_FLT_IF_NOT_FOUND). Make sure that you have one VirtualBox Host-Only Network adaptor. I had 2 machines that had 2 different adaptors so reinstall VB solved it.

Comment: Similar problem here with VirtualBox 6.0.8 - the above worked, but I had to manually add the NDIS driver: Install -> Oracle -> NDIS (long name) - then the adapter appeared again as an option in the Virtual Machine network settings 'name' drop down.

Answer (score 3):

I just had the same trouble, reinstalling virtualbox 5.0 worked really fine.

Comment: I had tried a repair and that failed, I uninstalled and installed again and that worked

Comment: For me, it was specifically installing 5.0.26 from here https://www.virtualbox.org/wiki/Download_Old_Builds_5_0

Answer (score 1):

I solved my problem installing the following versions of VirtualBox and Vagrant.

- VirtualBox 5.0.26 (I had 5.0.18)
- Vagrant 1.8.5 (I kept the same version)

As you can see I just uninstall VirtualBox and installed the 5.0.26 because Vagrant doesn't work with Virtualbox 5.1.x

Regards!

Comment: This worked for me and I also had to enable the network driver above too.  I couldn't even start VirtualBox to change the network settings too so doing this helped. You saved my life and I can't thank you enough. Thank you!

Answer (score 0):

I had this problem. Accepted solution did not work because the 'Host Only Adapter' did not have any options in the 'Name:' dropdown.

I solved this by selecting 'Attach to': 'Bridged Adapter' in vbox network setup, then the 'Name:' dropdown offered 'Ethernet Adapter #2' ....